# BMesh: does an edge include itself in the disk cycle?

Tags: edges, source-code

I'm basing my work on [BMeshUnity](https://github.com/eliemichel/BMeshUnity) and there's something that could be a bug in its disk cycle implementation.

Here's a log of a simple triangle face, numbers are indices for each element, focus on each Edge's "Vx Prev/Next Edges":

```
Face [0] has 3 verts, 1st Loop [2]
Loop [0] of Face [0], Edge [0], Vertex [0], Prev/Next Loop [2, 1], Prev/Next Radial [0, 0]
Loop [1] of Face [0], Edge [1], Vertex [1], Prev/Next Loop [0, 2], Prev/Next Radial [1, 1]
Loop [2] of Face [0], Edge [2], Vertex [2], Prev/Next Loop [1, 0], Prev/Next Radial [2, 2]
Edge [0] with Verts [0, 1], Loop [0], V0 Prev/Next Edges [2, 2], V1 Prev/Next Edges [1, 1]
Edge [1] with Verts [1, 2], Loop [1], V0 Prev/Next Edges [0, 0], V1 Prev/Next Edges [2, 2]
Edge [2] with Verts [2, 0], Loop [2], V0 Prev/Next Edges [1, 1], V1 Prev/Next Edges [0, 0]
Vertex [0] at (0.00, 0.00, 0.00), base Edge [0]
Vertex [1] at (1.00, 0.10, 1.00), base Edge [0]
Vertex [2] at (2.00, 2.00, 2.00), base Edge [1]
```

Given Edge[0] the V0 prev/next are both set to the only other Edge connecting to V0: Edge[2].

My question is: should there be a self-reference in the Vertex0 Prev/Next edge? Or should this be avoided?

I guess the latter makes sense from the point of traversing the graph, since you always want to go to a different prev/next edge than the one you are coming from.

In other words, for a triangle face should prev/next it be (A) with self-references:

```
Edge [0]:  V0 Prev/Next Edges [2, 0], V1 Prev/Next Edges [0, 1]
Edge [1]:  V0 Prev/Next Edges [0, 1], V1 Prev/Next Edges [1, 2]
Edge [2]:  V0 Prev/Next Edges [1, 2], V1 Prev/Next Edges [2, 0]
```

Or should it be (B) without self-references:

```
Edge [0]:  V0 Prev/Next Edges [2, 2], V1 Prev/Next Edges [0, 0]
Edge [1]:  V0 Prev/Next Edges [0, 0], V1 Prev/Next Edges [1, 1]
Edge [2]:  V0 Prev/Next Edges [1, 1], V1 Prev/Next Edges [2, 2]
```

I hope for confirmation from someone more intimate with BMesh disk cycles. Thanks!